# Solving this ODE: getting a non-sensical result - why?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm considering the ODE:

$$ \frac{dV}{dx} = \frac{1}{36} V ( 8 - 3 V^2 ) \sqrt{ 3 V^2 + 16 } $$

I can separate the above in the following manner so that I get:

$$-\frac{8}{9} x = 32 \int \left[ \sqrt{ 3 V^{2} + 16 } \left( 3 V^{2} - 8 \right) V \right]^{-1} dV $$

Using regular substitution with the variable $\mu = \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{3 V^{2} + 16}$ (where $d \mu = \frac{ \frac{3}{4} V }{ \sqrt{ 3 V^{2} + 16 } }$), this becomes:

$$-\frac{8}{9} x = \int \frac{ d \mu }{( 3 - 2 \mu^{2} ) ( \mu^{2} - 1 ) }$$

With Wolfram Alpha, I then get:

$$- \frac{8}{9}x = \tanh^{-1} (\mu) \ + \ \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \tanh^{-1} \left( \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \mu \right)$$

And substituting back for V, we get:

$$- \frac{8}{9}x = \tanh^{-1} (\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{3V^2+16}) \ + \ \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \tanh^{-1} \left( \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{3V^2+16} \right)$$

Now define the function $g:\mathbb{R} \to (0,1)$ as $g(y) =  \tanh^{-1} (y) \ + \ \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \tanh^{-1} \left( \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} y \right)$. Then $g$ has a smooth inverse, which I call $g^{-1}(y)=\mathrm{tunh}(x)$. Note that $\mathrm{tunh}(y)$ maps onto $(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Then the above can be written as:

$$-\frac{8}{9} x = g\left( \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{3V^2+16} \right)$$

Which implies that:

$$\mathrm{tunh}(-\frac{8}{9}x) = \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{3V^2+16}$$

And finally, solving for $V$, I finally get:

$$V(x) = \sqrt{\frac{16}{3}} \sqrt{ \mathrm{tunh}^{2}(-\frac{8}{9}x) - 1 }$$

MY ISSUE:

Recall that $\mathrm{tunh}(y) \in (0,1)$. This would imply that my solution $V$ is complex! Why is this happening?

Comment: you have three constant solutions. $0, \sqrt{8/3}, - \sqrt{8/3}.$ This means that the nonconstant real solutions split into four types depending on the size and sign of $V.$ This is first order, so solutions do not cross, in particular they remain on the same side of any constant solution forever.

Answer (score 1):

You have three constant solutions, $V = 0,$ $V = \sqrt{8/3},$ $V = - \sqrt{8/3}.$

Between those you get the solutions that resemble $\arctan x$ or $\tanh x$ or their negatives.

Outside of those, you get solutions that approach one of the constants as time goes in one direction, but blow up in finite time as time goes in the other direction, meaning vertical asymptote. The reason we know it blows up is comparison: here, $|V'| \approx V^4.$ Compare things like $y' = 1 + y^2$ which lead to $y = \tan x,$ or just $y' = y^2$ which gives $y = -1/x.$ Or $y' = y^2 - 1,$ for $|y| > 1,$ I get $y = - \coth x,$ this is above $1$ for $x < 0$ but below $-1$ for $x < 0,$ vertical asymptote at $x=0$ for both. A reason for the somewhat unusual vertical symmetry of the picture is your square root quantity, which means for $|V|$ large we have $V' \approx - V^3 \,|V|,$ or $V'/V < 0$ when $|V|$ large.

There is no explicit dependence on $x$ in the ODE, meaning that every solution in one of the four regions is a translate of another solution in that region. They are all the same.

[image]